# Undefined Variable $db en php

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de eliminar un producto de mi base de datos a traves de un boton en mi php, sin embargo, en el mismo archivo soy capaz de traer los productos de la base de datos.

Cuando clickeo el boton me lleva a otra pagina y me dice un error que la variable $db no esta definida. Ademas cuando trato de mostrar el Id de cada producto, por alguna razon solo puedo mostrar correctamente el id del 1er y 2do producto, despues el 3er producto tiene el id del 2do (los nombres igual los muestra bien).

Estuve tratando de hacer echo de cosas random para ver hasta que punto llega mi codigo.

```
<?php 

    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "buffet");

    $sql_comida = "SELECT * FROM Producto where idCategoria = 1";
    $comidas = $db->query($sql_comida);
    if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
        $delete_id = (int)$_GET['idProducto'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Producto WHERE idProducto = '$delete_id'";
        $db->query($sql);
        header('Location: productos_admin.php');
    } 
?>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-auto table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th> </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while($auxiliar = $comidas->FETCH_ASSOC()): ?>
        <?php $comida = new Productos($auxiliar["idProducto"], $auxiliar["Nombre"], $auxiliar["Precio"], $auxiliar["Stock"], $auxiliar["RutaImagen"])?>
            <tr>
                <?php $comida->mostrarInformacionTabla(); ?>
                    <td>
                        <a href= "productos_admin.php?delete=<?= $comida->getIdProducto();?>" >
                            <button type='button' data-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <form action="includes/vistaAdmin/productos_admin.php" method="get">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" id="idProducto" value="<?php echo $comida->getIdProducto() ?>"/>
                                    </form>
                                </i>
                            </button>  
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>      
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hola, no hace falta que agregues la explicación en ingles, hablamos español.

Answer (score 1):

el problema parece en este punto:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
```

estas comprobando que este definido algo llamado "delete" dentro de las opciones del formulario que envias. Pero no tienes ningun campo llamado "delete". Veo dos opciones para solucionar esto:

1.- añade un campo "delete" en el formulario:

```
<form action="includes/vistaAdmin/productos_admin.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" id="idProducto" value="<?php echo $comida->getIdProducto() ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="delete" />
</form>
```

2.- la comprobación debes hacerla sobre el metodo que se esta enviado:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') && !empty($_GET['idProducto'])){
```

Veo mas logico la 2a.

Por otra parte, date cuenta que estas enviando un id por un get, cosa que no es correcta. En su lugar, el formulario deberia ser DELETE (puesto que precisamente es lo que quieres hacer).

**LA SOLUCION** o lo que yo consideraria correcto seria:

comprobar que nos envian un metodo DELETE y tenemos en el request el idProducto definido:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE') && !empty($_REQUEST['idProducto'])){
```

y por otra en el formulario enviarlo como delete:

```
<form action="includes/vistaAdmin/productos_admin.php" method="delete">
  <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" id="idProducto" value="<?php echo $comida->getIdProducto() ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Te me adelantaste! muy bien explicado y buena solución, aunque si no usas estrictamente php, te recomendaría también hacer el delete por ajax, es muy fácil y mucho mas usable, un saludo!

Comment: pero el delete por ajax requiere un php que haga el propio delete... o existe alguna manera de que ajax llame a bbdd y ejecute la consulta?

Comment: por ajax llamas a otro php que simplemente coja el id del dom y lo pase a la consulta delete